# I am trying to use a class to hold a string value but it is not returning the value I inputted

Tags: c++, class

So basically I'm putting in a string into a variable and it is not returning the right value.

The Class that is storing the value:

```
#include "livestreamer.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void setStream(string x);
string getStream();

livestreamer::livestreamer()
{

}

void livestreamer::setStream(string x){
    stream = x;
}

string livestreamer::getStream(){
    return stream;
}
```

The class that is giving the value:

```
#include "streamwindow.h"
#include "ui_streamwindow.h"
#include "livestreamer.h"
#include "startstream.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



streamwindow::streamwindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::streamwindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

streamwindow::~streamwindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void streamwindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}

void streamwindow::on_pushButton_17_clicked()
{
    livestreamer st;
    st.setStream("tsm_dyrus");
    startstream s;
    s.reallystartstream();
}
```

The class that is using the value:

```
#include "startstream.h"
#include "livestreamer.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

startstream::startstream()
{

}

void startstream::reallystartstream(){
    livestreamer obj;
    system(("livestreamer twitch.tv/"+obj.getStream()+" best").c_str());

}
```

And what is happening is that I run it and it just doesn't return the value at all. So if anyone can try and help me that would be great.

Comment: But you have no classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the type of `livestreamer::stream` is `std::string`.

You create two objects, and store a value in one object, and then retreive it from the second.  The second object does not contain the value of the first object, you need to pass the first object.

In your streamwindow::on_pushButton_17_clicked():

```
void streamwindow::on_pushButton_17_clicked()
{
    livestreamer st;
    st.setStream("tsm_dyrus");
    startstream s;
    s.reallystartstream( st );
}
```

And then your startstream class:

```
void startstream::reallystartstream( livestreamer & obj ){
    system(("livestreamer twitch.tv/"+obj.getStream()+" best").c_str());
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good guess - that's true of `on_pushButton_17_clicked()` unless `livestream::stream` is `static`, which we can't tell without the header.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for not really giving too much information. It was late last night and I am very new to c++. This did solve my problem. :)